# Creating Shapefile of subset of input features in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm having some trouble applying my Python skills to develop some scripts in PyQGIS. For me it's far simpler to write it in ArcPy, but then again I wouldn't get that much satisfaction after finishing my project. Trying to work with open source tools as much as possible.

In short, for now I want to write a Python script that takes in a shapefile and from that generates another one with some specific attribute data related to buildings. If I were doing it in ArcPy, my algorithm would be the following: use the MakeFeature Layer_management, then perform a SelectLayerByLocation_management, within the selection select the data you need, and then create another layer with desired data.

How could I this in PyQGIS?

One idea, reading the PyQGIS Cookbook, to use .getFeatures(), QgsVectorFileWriter to write the shapefile, but how do I perform the query?

Comment: Can you expand your script, because if you want to use Open Source tools you can even do that in Python only without ArcPy or PyQGIS

Comment: Sure I can, it was only meant as a starting point. Hmm, I haven't tried or thought about that before.

Comment: However, isn't there a need for a cursor-like object that's already implemented in the PyQGIS core library? Can you do that simply by Python? I don't see how...

Comment: Only ArcPy use cursors to call ArGIS commands (same with Python database modules), PyQGIS and Geospatial Python modules don't need cursors (only Python)

Comment: In any case, thank you @gene. I'll change my approach accordingly.